# Todd-Coxeter algorithm: coincidences

Tags: group-theory, algorithms, computer-science, symbolic-computation, computational-algebra

I'm trying to understand the Todd-Coxeter algorithm with the help of a multiplication and relator table, but there is one thing about coincidences that is not really clear.

For some small groups (for example 4 or 10 elements), everything is straightforward (by means of coincidences). But with some bigger examples, it can happen that multiple coincidences appear at the same time/iteration, in worst case even some cycles of coincidences. I'm wondering in which order (and how) I should solve these coincidences...

Hopefully someone can help me with this problem!

Comment: The general idea is to maintain a queue of coincidences for processing. Each time you find a new one $(a,b)$, first go through the queue and, if $a$ or $b$ are already in the queue to be eliminated, replace them by what they will get replaced by, and then if the resulting pair $(a',b')$ are still distinct, add them to the queue. That will avoid cycles. For full technical details, you need pseudocode, which you can find in a book.

Comment: @ABC: Is there any certain example in your mind? Is there any certain group u waana work on it via this way? May be I can help you. :-)